# rpmbuild: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found - Multiple options tried

Tags: packaging, rpm, rpmbuild

This is getting rather maddening - I'm trying to build an RPM out of some BASH scripts which work as Nagios plugins.  I keep getting:

```
error: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
    /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/netappassigncheck
    /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/netappassignprep
```

In the %files directive of my spec file I have tried most of the combos that have been suggested here and on various other internet forums:

- /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/*
- /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/netappassigncheck
- /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/netappassignprep
- %dir /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/

And currently I am on

```
%dir %{_libdir}/nagios/plugins/
```

This is why my most recent error output is lib64, previous errors when quoting the full path were /usr/lib/...

These are the only 2 files that should make up the package as well.

Here is my .spec file

```
Name: netappautoassign
Summary: A set of Nagios Plugins for automatically assigning disks to a Netapp
Version: 1.0
Release: 1
License: %{license}
Group: Applications/System
Source: %{source}
URL: Reserved
Vendor: %{vendor}
Packager: %{packager}
BuildArch: noarch
Requires: bash, grep, util-linux, coreutils, expect, openssh-clients, bc, sed
Provides: netappassignprep, netappassigncheck
%description
Since Netapp's autoassign function may lead to disks being assigned to the
wrong head these NAGIOS plugins will ensure disks are added to the correct
head when replaced.

%prep
%setup -q

%build

%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
install -d %{buildroot}%{_libdir}/nagios/plugins
cp netappassigncheck %{buildroot}%{_libdir}/nagios/plugins/
cp netappassignprep %{buildroot}%{_libdir}/nagios/plugins/

%files
%defattr(755,root,root,755)
%dir %{_libdir}/nagios/plugins/

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}

%post
```

And here's my ~/.rpmmacros

```
%_topdir %(echo $HOME)/rpmbuild
%_tmppath %{_topdir}/tmp
%buildroot %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}

%license RESERVED
%source %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
%vendor REDACTED
%packager REDACTED
```

**EDIT - SOLVED**

I'm not sure if this is a bug or desired behaviour, but it would appear that during the build setion the %{buildroot} variable was not being read in from .rpmmacros Having moved this variable into the main spec file the RPM is now built.

Comment: As you already noted there must be a difference between the stuff you copied to buildroot and the expressions in the %files section. Check your files in the 'buildroot' (remove the %clean part)

Comment: I've just tried removing the %clean section, and the "rm -rf" line from %install.  Still the same error.

`[user@stor-wb-d1 plugins]$ pwd`
`/home/user/rpmbuild/tmp/netappautoassign-1.0/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins`
`[user@stor-wb-d1 plugins]$ ls -al`
`total 16`
`drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Dec  7 13:02 .`
`drwxr-xr-x 3 user user 4096 Dec  7 13:02 ..`
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 1902 Dec  7 13:03 netappassigncheck`
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 2170 Dec  7 13:03 netappassignprep`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a bug or desired behaviour, but it would appear that during the file verification section, it was reading in all the current active plugins under the root file system and not the %{buildroot}.

I suspected that the %{buildroot} variable was not being read in from .rpmmacros at this stage, although it was for all other stages.

I moved the declaration of %{buildroot} into my main .spec file and the build is now working!

Comment: did you try `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` instead? What OS are you trying to build your packed on?